# Is it possible to globally set a default `ids` function for pytest's parametrize?

Tags: python, pytest

`pytest.mark.parametrize` accepts an `ids` argument which can be a callable, like this:

```py
def test_id_builder(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, int):
        return str(arg)

    ... # more logic

@pytest.mark.parametrize('value', [1, 2], ids=test_id_builder)
def test_whatever(value):
    assert value > 0
```

This will generate two test cases, with the ids `"1"` and `"2"` respectively. The problem is that I have *a lot* of tests, organized in multiple classes and files. Because of that, I'd like to globally set `test_id_builder` as the `ids` function for *all* parametrized tests in my project. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply implement a custom [`pytest_make_parametrize_id`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_make_parametrize_id) hook. In your `conftest.py`:

```py
def pytest_make_parametrize_id(config, val, argname):
    if isinstance(val, int):
        return f'{argname}={val}'
    if isinstance(val, str):
        return f'text is {val}'
    # return None to let pytest handle the formatting
    return None
```

Example tests:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize('n', range(3))
def test_int(n):
    assert True

@pytest.mark.parametrize('s', ('fizz', 'buzz'))
def test_str(s):
    assert True


@pytest.mark.parametrize('c', (tuple(), list(), set()))
def test_unhandled(c):
    assert True
```

Check the test parametrizing:

```
$ pytest -q --collect-only 
test_spam.py::test_int[n=0]
test_spam.py::test_int[n=1]
test_spam.py::test_int[n=2]
test_spam.py::test_str[text is fizz]
test_spam.py::test_str[text is buzz]
test_spam.py::test_unhandled[c0]
test_spam.py::test_unhandled[c1]
test_spam.py::test_unhandled[c2]

no tests ran in 0.06 seconds
```

Comment: Now *this* looks like a clean solution. One thing, though: `return val` only works if `val` is a string; according to the docs the correct way let pytest handle it is to return `None`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey glad I could help! Actually, I made an error in the answer; `return val` should be replaced with `return None` if you want to delegate arg representation to `pytest`. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your custom `parametrize`:

```
import pytest

def id_builder(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, int):
        return str(arg) * 2

def custom_parametrize(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('ids', id_builder)
    return pytest.mark.parametrize(*args, **kwargs)

@custom_parametrize('value', [1, 2])
def test_whatever(value):
    assert value > 0
```

And to avoid rewriting `pytest.mark.parametrize` to `custom_parametrize` everywhere use this well-known workaround:

```
old_parametrize = pytest.mark.parametrize

def custom_parametrize(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('ids', id_builder)
    return old_parametrize(*args, **kwargs)

pytest.mark.parametrize = custom_parametrize
```

Comment: This *feels* like bad design... but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to `globally` set ids. but yo can use [pytest-generate-tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.0/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests) to generate tests from some `other` fixture. that `other` fixture could be scoped to `session` which overall will mimic the intended behaviour.